# multiple keys in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have multiple environments and it needs the specific username and password to login. I will select the environment from a drop down list(DEV, UAT, PRD). So when I click an environment from the drop down list, it should store the username and password of the identified environment in the cs file.

In my `web.config` file:

```
  <add key="DEPTA_DEV_cbUserName" value="owjfe8" />
  <add key="DEPTA_DEV_cbPassw" value="HkvdC" />

  <add key="DEPTB_DEV_cbUserName" value="qwrwr23" />
  <add key="DEPTB_DEV_cbPassw" value="bgfbbbd" />

  <add key="DEPTA_UAT_cbUserName" value="qatsze1" />
  <add key="DEPTA_UAT_cbPassw" value="wswe4rx2" />

  <add key="DEPTB_UAT_cbUserName" value="eyyyiidc3" />
  <add key="DEPTB_UAT_cbPassw" value="rftytv4" />

  <add key="DEPTA_PRD_cbUserName" value="tgy6utyygb3" />
  <add key="DEPTA_PRD_cbPassw" value="yhfhdfhn6" />

  <add key="DEPTB_PRD_cbUserName" value="ujhfdhdfdm7" />
  <add key="DEPTB_PRD_cbPassw" value="plmhy99" />
```

In my `.cs` file:

```
 string userName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[];
```

what should be in the .AppSettings[] bracket?

Comment: Hi! I'm having trouble understanding what is the question here. Could you please edit to explicate what it is you're asking here?

Comment: @vijoc hi sorry i have edited.